# Express list comprehension as for loop

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around list comprehensions and try to get some practice by taking examples and form loops out of comprehensions and vice versa. Probably a really easy mistake, or a forest for the trees situation. Take the following expression taken from an example project:

```
rows = []
data = ['a', 'b']
res = ['1', '2']

rows.append({data[counter]: res[counter] for counter, _ in enumerate(data)})
```

print(rows):
`[{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}]`

How do i do this as a for loop? The following wraps each loop into a curly bracket instead of both.

```
for counter, _ in enumerate(data):
   rows.append({data[counter]: res[counter]})
```

print(rows):
`[{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}]`

Am i missing something? Or do i have to merge the items by hand when using a for loop?

Comment: You are appending a dictionary, and the dictionary is built in a dictionary comprehension, what you can do is change the dictionary comprehension for a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you create a dictionary for each item in `data` and append it to rows in each iteration.

In order to achieve the desired behaviour, you should update the same dict in each iteration and after you finish working on your dictionary, only then you should append it to rows.

Try this:

```
rows = []
data = ['a', 'b']
res = ['1', '2']
payload = {}
for counter, val in enumerate(data):
   payload[val] = res[counter]
rows.append(payload)
```

Another compact way to write it might be:

```
rows.append(dict(zip(data,res)))
```

Comment: Thank you, i think i got the difference between the comprehensions (plural) and the for loop. I tried the zip() version as well, very interesting. But it works for the provided example but not in my code. Since you wrote "might" do you have any idea what could cause a "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"? I understand that it is telling me that i try to call a list with (), but shouldn't that error happen in your example already? The type of data and res is <class 'list'> <class 'list'> in both cases.

Comment: it's difficult to say what can cause your error without seeing the code and the traceback. I guess that there is some place that you're trying to access an element within the list with parenthesis instead of square brackets (in this case, the error you mentioned will be thrown)

Answer (score -1):

On every iteration of for loop you are creating a new dictionary and appending it into a list if you want to store a whole dictionary in a list then You should try something like that it outputs as you expected:

```
rows = []
data = ['a', 'b']
res = ['1', '2']
myDict = {}
for counter, _ in enumerate(data):
   myDict[data[counter]]= res[counter]
rows.append(myDict)
print(rows)
```

Output:

```
[{'b': '2', 'a': '1'}]
```